# Continuous capturing of an area on screen

Tags: c#, performance, screen-capture, continuous

I have a problem with screen capturing in C#. I need to continuously read an 100x100 px area from screen and analyze every frame (pixel by pixel).

Right now I am using Graphics.CopyFromScreen, but it slows my whole computer down more than Crysis 3.

I've seen a DirectX (using SlimDX) way of doing it, but converting a Surface into a Bitmap takes a lot of time.

Perhaps I could draw that Surface directly on my preview PictureBox/Panel, but I have no idea how to do it or even how to read pixel data from that Surface.

Any help much appreciated